# friend system which does not work

Tags: php, mysqli

It is so right now I'm working on making a good friend system like facebook as I'd like it to be it;

- See if you are friends and if it is then it will say "friends"
- If it is such that you are not friends must have the ability to apply personal friendship.

**$fra_id** it is him as a candidate
**$tid_id** it is to him you want to be friends
**$godkendt_ven** it's whether you have been approved or not. if it is 0 so that it has not been approved but if it is 1 then the friends.

```
 if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)
            {
                echo "<ul>";
                //Posts to he
                echo "<li class=\"ProfilIndhold_top_b\">Beskede</li>";
                    if ($stmt1 = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `fra_id`, `til_id`, `godkendt_ven` FROM `venner` WHERE `fra_id` = ? OR `til_id` = ?')) { 
                    $stmt1->bind_param('ii', $fra_id, $til_id);
                    $fra_id = $_SESSION["id"];
                    $til_id = $_SESSION["id"];

                    $stmt1->execute();
                    $stmt1->bind_result($fra_id, $til_id, $godkendt_ven);
                        while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
                            /*
                            if($_GET["id"] == $_SESSION["id"])
                            {
                                //can not add myself
                                echo "<li class=\"ProfilIndhold_top_a\">Kan ikke</li>";
                            }
                            */
                            elseif($_GET["id"] != $_SESSION["id"])
                            {
                                if($godkendt_ven == 0 and $til_id != $_GET["id"] or $fra_id != $_GET["id"])
                                {
                                    //Can add to friends
                                    echo "<li class=\"ProfilIndhold_top_a\">Tilføj</li>";
                                }
                                if($godkendt_ven == 1 and $til_id == $_GET["id"] or $fra_id == $_GET["id"])
                                {
                                    //We are friends
                                    echo "<li class=\"ProfilIndhold_top_a\">Venner</li>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    $stmt1->close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'There was an error in the declaration: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
                    }
                echo "<ul>";
            }
            //Showing no matter what this content
```

so my question is whether you can do several ways such that one check for the example user 1 and user 2 are friends so they will not be able to apply each other again.

Questions then you'd ask me again if there is anything you want to know ..

**Hope you can help me**

Comment: so basically you're SELECTing all rows where fra_id=ii OR til_id=ii, when ii is your user id. right?